# Vite React App - Unexpected Token Index.js

Tags: reactjs, vite

I would like some help to understand this problem and what might be causing it. I recently migrated my react application from create-react-app to vite, following the vite documentation. Prior to migrating, I did not have this kind of error.

It seems to be random white pages. Some browsers will do it, sometimes on desktop, sometimes on mobile. If I clear the cache of the browser, the issue will go away and it will load the page. The exception is unexpected token in index.js. I checked several other threads on StackOverflow and GitHub Issues and none of those seemed to resolve the issue I am experiencing.

- I added 'base: "/"' and the build output directory into my vite.config.ts
- I added 'window.global ||= window;' into the top of my index.tsx file
- I set my entire application to be lazy loaded; and a large chunk of it (After Authentication) to be lazy loaded as well.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "types": ["vite/client", "vitest/globals"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "preserveWatchOutput": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

vite.config.ts:

```
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')
  return {
    build: {
      outDir: "build",
      sourcemap: false
    },
    plugins: [
      react(),
      tsconfigPaths()
    ],
    server: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 3000,
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: env.VITE_APP_PROXY_ENDPOINT || 'https://localhost:7019',
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: false
        }
      },
      headers: {
        "x-frame-options": "sameorigin",
        "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
        'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=43200'
      }
    },
    base: "/"
  }
});
```

I am using the command npm run build:web, to deploy the application as a static app hosted on IIS, this is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(docs)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                //Security Headers Are Here with my Domain Configuration
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Edit: What is strange is I can also get it to happen by clearing my cache. When I do a new deployment, the page might load and then when I clear my cache it goes white screen.
[image: Unexpected Token Console Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the solution to my problem. I am using @babel, which references core-js and I had installed core-js and was importing the entire core-js in my Index.tsx file. I believe when it was building the webpack this was causing some major issues. I was previously transforming 2,516 modules when building the webpack and I am now transforming 435.

Note: Do not install and import the entire core-js library.